# Test doesn't execute method unless I assert on the method's returned value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

Ok, I have a strange problem.

I'm using NUnit and Moq in a C# Test project. I think you can ignore the Mock-objects, since the real problem lies in UserManager.AddUser() not being properly executed.

The following code will never reach the breakpoint at the start of UserManager.AddUser(), and will thereby fail on the Assertion due to NullPointerException.

```cs
[Test]
enter code here
public void AddUser_NoPassword_GeneratesPassword()
    {
        //assert
        var userRepositoryFake = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        userRepositoryFake.Setup(x => x.GetUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns((User)null);
        userRepositoryFake.Setup(x => x.SaveUser(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(new Mock<User>().Object);

        var userManager = new UserManager(userRepositoryStub.Object);
        var createUserViewModel = new CreateUserViewModel { Username = "username" };

        //act
        var validationErrors = userManager.AddUser(createUserViewModel);

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(createUserViewModel.Password);
    }
```

However, if I add this assertion:

```cs
        //assert
        Assert.IsEmpty(validationErrors); //new assertion
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(createUserViewModel.Password);
```

The breakpoint in AddUser() is reached, and the test succeeds. 
It seems the test doesn't execute AddUser() at all, unless its return-value is used for something.

Comment: Can you post the code to AddUser?

Comment: @user1770699: What is the return value of AddUser? If it is IEnumerable, has it been enumerated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that `AddUser` is implemented like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Error> AddUser(Model model)
{
    // Do some stuff
    if (foo)
    {
        yield return ...;
    }
    if (bar)
    {
        yield return ...;
    } 
    // More stuff
}
```

In other words, using an iterator block. Iterator blocks are executed lazily - the code only starts executing when the first element is requested, and even then it will "pause" when that element has been returned.

Given that this isn't an idempotent query or anything like that, I suggest it would make a lot more sense to implement the method using a `List<Error>` internally which you add to and then return at the end. That way the method will get executed *exactly once* however many times the return value is iterated over. That's the *expected* model of execution, I suspect.

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned something new about yield return.